# Как загрузить картинку из Resourses в объект на сцене в UNITY?

Tags: c#, unity3d, resources

Имеется `GameObject` c именем `222`, с компонентом `SpriteRenderer`.
В скрипте, активируемом по нажатии кнопки, следующее:

```
GameObject.Find ("222").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Logo/ATL");
//Logo - папка в ресурсах, соответственно.
```

В компонент `gameobject` сохраняется спрайт, но нигде не отображается на сцене. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем я ошибся?

Comment: GameObject.Find ("222").GetComponent ().sprite - такой код даже компилироваться не будет, потому что метод GetComponent имеет обязательный параметр типа. Возможно вы неправильно скопировали код в свой вопрос?

Comment: прежде чем задать вопрос, посетите сайт с документацией. Вот пример использование вашего метода: `boxCol = otherGameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();`. Только не забудьте тип на нужный вам поменять.

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю, что лучше не мудрить и не умещать всё в одну строчку.
Разумней создать префаб со спрайтом. В картинке надо изменить тип текстуры на Sprite:
[image: Спрайт]
Затем можно просто перетащить картинку на сцену (будет создан объект-sprite), а потом, создав в проекте префаб, присвоить ему этот объект.
Ну а далее дело за малым:

```
GameObject twotwotwo;
void Start()
{
    twotwotwo = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("ATL-Prefab"));
    // ...ну и тут ты делаешь то, что тебе надо...
}
```

У меня всё заработало.

С Resources.Load() не знаю, как быть. У меня возникает ошибка **"InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type."**, и у меня тоже ничего нет. Так что, я считаю, лучше использовать префабы; они работают.